# Google compute engine console return 399 error code

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I try to reach (after login) https://cloud.google.com/console I get a 399 error code:

```
Remote Address:212.179.154.246:443
Request URL:https://cloud.google.com/console
Request Method:GET
```

And the response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 399 Internal Server Error
status: 399 Internal Server Error
version: HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 141
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 13 May 2014 12:01:20 GMT
expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: Google Frontend
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-frame-options: DENY
x-pan-versionid: racy-novel-20140502-rc22.375698005067444148
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Using other devices works, and sometimes using the incognito mode works as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a strange error! Perhaps try connecting directly to the new console at https://console.developers.google.com/ ?