# Google compute engine returned 399 internal server error

Tags: google-app-engine, wget, google-cloud-storage

[Google compute engine console return 399 error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630852/google-compute-engine-console-return-399-error-code) already asks my question but the solution is not as suggested there. Since the URL is little old starting a new thread.

I am trying to do a wget using:

```
    wget https://console.developers.google.com/m/cloudstorage/b/m-lab/o/ndt/2012/05/23/20120523T000000Z-mlab1-ams01-ndt-0000.tgz
```

I see the error:

```
Resolving console.developers.google.com (console.developers.google.com)... 216.239.32.27
Connecting to console.developers.google.com (console.developers.google.com)|216.239.32.27|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 399 Internal Server Error
2014-08-26 20:02:18 ERROR 399: Internal Server Error.
```

I am new to Linux commands so wanted to know if am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot download with traditional tools we have to use gsutil utility provided by google, using which automation is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The address works when I use Chrome downloader but fails with wget with me as well
I have never seen this behaviour before 
You can also use cURL to download files, I used the -v switch and got a dns error(no idea why)

```
curl -v http://console.developers.googlO.com/m/cloudstorage/b/m-lab/o/ndt/2012/05/23/20120523T000000Z-mlab1-ams01-ndt-0000.tgz
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630852/google-compute-engine-console-return-399-error-code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following URI pattern:

`http://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>`

In this case, you can download that file using the command:

`wget http://storage.googleapis.com/m-lab/ndt/2012/05/23/20120523T000000Z-mlab1-ams01-ndt-0000.tgz`

Comment: yes but its only manual, your way automation is atleast difficult and time consuming.